# What is this movable NVMe screw and how do I find a replacement?

Tags: ssd, nvme, screws

I bought a used Dell Precision 3450 and want to add some additional NVMe storage. However, one of the drive positions seems to support either 2230 or 2280 and does not come pre-installed with a little support post to screw into.

I Googled around and found that the post itself is a screw and is movable, and seems to have threading in the top for the smaller NVMe screw.

What is the part number or what keywords to use to find either an exact or similar replacement?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's called a M.2 SSD Standoff. Most Desktop Standoffs will be cross compatible.